# How to embedded terminal in desktop background?

Tags: design

How to embedded terminal in desktop background like heare:

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-PemdPbbGgTs/UM1X1evKmcI/AAAAAAAAAWg/go4C0UMe7Jg/s870/Screenshot-94.png]

?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a terminal window opened without borders and with a transparent background. You can archive this with urxvt or tilda term , for example, by configurating them to open in the middle of the screen.

The only thing I couldn't change was that the window showed in the window list bar.